# Duplicate dylib warning in xcode

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios, dylib

I received this warning after adding the flurry api:

```
ld: warning: duplicate dylib /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator4.2.sdk/usr/lib/system/libSystem.host.dylib
```

I do not understand what I have to do to get rid of this. Any hints would be real helpful.

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well you need to find that duplicate file first,You are having that file more than once thats why its happening , and then delete that file and moreover also delete the app from the simulator.Remove the build,clean the targets and then run your app.Hope it would help you dear.....
Have a great time and coding bro....

Comment: Well, thank you very much, as it turns out I had added other linker flags such as /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib, but forgot why, I thought I had to, so that flurry would work, but I guess not, what I did was go to the file in question in the warning 'libSystem.host.dylib' and doubled clicked this opened the terminal that had this text 'libSystem.B.dylib' which was the clue I needed so after removing for linker flags it compiled fine, thanks for you time

Comment: My pleasure bro well it helped you thats really nice to me,That is why all people are here to help each other.Well bro you accepted the answer but didn't vote up for me.please do vote up my answer as it will help me as well as also help to make your acceptance and reputation on stack overflow..

Comment: It's required for FLurry to work. If you do not do it, it will crash on 3.x

Answer (score 0):

Check your target compile resources and bundle resources for duplicate objects.