# Duplicate dylib

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

Is there a general solution for "Duplicate dylib" warning when building Xcode project?
I've seen these two posts and but they are not enough information to me.

[Safely resolve dylib warning?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5270558/safely-resolve-dylib-warning)

[Duplicate dylib warning in xcode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4536487/duplicate-dylib-warning-in-xcode)

My warning is:

```
ld: warning: duplicate dylib /Xcode3.2.5/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator4.2.sdk/usr/lib/system/libSystem.host.dylib
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also have that library twice in my Xcode installation, so the problem does not lie with the file being duplicated, but with your project linking it twice.

I suggest first of all to make a clean build, the build again. If your project is ok, this should fix it.

EDIT:

Then, I think that your project got somehow corrupted when doing an upgrade from one Xcode version to another (I am just guessing based on my experience). Could you check in the framework section of your project if you have multiple libSystem? Ideally, you should open the `*.project` file inside you project bundle (it's a text file) and search there for any appearance of libSystem... see whether you find anything suspect...

Comment: I did a clean build and do the build again, when I build with |DEVICE| everything is ok, but when I build with |SIMULATOR| this warning appears.

Comment: Thanks sergio, I'd try and let you know the result.